# Hadoop Mapreduce stuck and never completes

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am using Pig to store data into hive. I have a problem that when I execute program, it shows 0% complete and stuck and never completed. I run around 3 hours but never showed any problem. I started searching and found the problem might be in `yarn.xml` and `map_reduce.xml` configuration. I changed configuration, but it never effected at all.

Comment: Check your nodemanager is in active/healthy state.

Comment: I think nodemanger is ok because i run hive and it is ok

Comment: Hive doesn't run MR job for all queries. Any way check nodemanager status in resource manager UI.